# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module with OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf, openlayers, es6-modules

I am new using OpenLayers (an open-source JavaScript library for displaying map data in web browsers as slippy maps). I am using it with Thymeleaf (a Java XML/XHTML/HTML5 template engine that can work both in web and non-web environments).

I have this piece of code:

```html
<div class="windowContentMap">
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
        <script>
          /*<![CDATA[*/
          import '/pradera/css/ol.css';
          import Map from '/css/Map';
          import View from '/css/View';
          import TileLayer from '/css/layer/Tile';
          import OSM from '/css/source/OSM';

          var map = new Map({
            layers: [
              new TileLayer({
                source: new OSM()
              })
            ],
            target: 'map',
            view: new View({
              projection: 'EPSG:4326',
              center: [0, 0],
              zoom: 2
            })
          });
          /*]]>*/
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

but on the line  import `'/pradera/css/ol.css';`

I have this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because, as the error states, you cannot use the `import` statement outside an ES6 module.

To solve it, make your script to a module by adding `type="module"` to your script tag, like:

```html
<div class="windowContentMap">
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
        <script type="module">
          /*<![CDATA[*/
          import '/pradera/css/ol.css';
          import Map from '/css/Map';
          import View from '/css/View';
          import TileLayer from '/css/layer/Tile';
          import OSM from '/css/source/OSM';

          var map = new Map({
            layers: [
              new TileLayer({
                source: new OSM()
              })
            ],
            target: 'map',
            view: new View({
              projection: 'EPSG:4326',
              center: [0, 0],
              zoom: 2
            })
          });
          /*]]>*/
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Read more about ES6 modules](https://javascript.info/modules-intro)